# Где должен хранится файл БД .db?

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Есть приложение, у которого уже большое кол-во пользователей. В этом приложении есть БД. Обычно, по умолчанию, в андроиде файл БД сохраняется в data/data/myApp/databases/myDb.db. Но в моём приложении этот файл хранится в data/data/myApp/files/myDb.db. База отлично обновляется при обновлении приложения у пользователя и вроде всё работает хорошо.

**Собственно вопрос:** Плохо ли то, что файл бд хранится не в том месте? Если плохо, то возможно ли перенести его у пользователей при новом обновлении и как?

Comment: главное что она хранится под `data/data/myApp/`. Остальное не принципиально, помоему

Comment: @Chubatiy искал об этом инфу в офф. доке, но там ни слова про это не нашёл. Решил задать вопрос, мб кто-то сталкивался с этим